# Equation to the summation to $ 3\cdot 10^{-n-1}$

Tags: exponential-sum

What would the equation to sum (shown below) of $ 3\cdot 10^{-n-1}$? Just like $ 2^x-1$ is the sum of $ 2^{x-1}$.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3\cdot 10^{-n-1}$$

This would be 0.3+0.03+0.003. . .

this would help me greatly in finding a limit for something.

UPDATE: I found (via calculator) it's $0.3021339806 \times 0.099570245^{x}$ but I'd like something smoother

Comment: The sum of that series is actually $\frac{100}3$, not $\frac13$, and it’s equal to $\frac{100}3$, not approaching it. But it’s not clear what you’re asking.

Comment: You keep changing the question. I think you mean $\sum 3\cdot 10^{-n}$. I also think you need to get more of a grip on geometric series to do this. The sum you are looking for is equal to 1/3, not $0.3021339806\times 0.099570245^x$ (what is $x$ supposed to be?)

Comment: I would delete this post and start over if I could. Sorry.

Comment: Don't worry about changing the question, even if you realize more than once that you've misstated something. What you currently have in the sum still doesn't match up with $0.3+0.03+...$ as you've written below. 

If the latter is what the sum should be, you should leave everything the same except for starting the sum at $n=0$, so the first term is $\frac{3}{10}$. In that case, as you noted in an earlier version, the sum is $\frac{1}{3}$; if you leave the summation starting at $n=1$ as now, the sum is $\frac{1}{30}$.

Answer (score 4):

You have that

$$0.3 + 0.03 + 0.003 +  \cdots  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{3}{{{{10}^n}}}} $$

Now use that $$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{a^n}}  = \frac{a}{{1 - a}}$$

whenever $|a|<1$

Comment: sorry i was unclear, the question was updated

Comment: @WebMaster You want to find $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{a^k}}  = {s_n(a)}$$ for $n$ and $a$ arbitrary?

Comment: Or you want to find $s_n$ such that $s_n-s_{n-1}=10^{2-n}$?

Comment: I want to find 0.3+0.03+0.003. So I think the first one

Comment: @WebMaster I edited. I guess you can work it out.